# Combinar columnas y celdas

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap

Utilizo `Bootstrap-tables` y quisiera combinar algunas celdas ejemplo:

```
0:{mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO AGRICOLA", pres: "20",…}
1:{mcNombre: "Acolchado Multicolor", pres: "20",…}
```

Mi `JSON` me tare e sos datos entonces quiero que si por ejemplo lo de la variable `pres` son iguales 20, 20 o 23,23 etc, me agrupe esas dos que solo aparezca una vez.
utilizo `Bootstrap-tables` y lei que puedo ocupar la propiedad `mergeCells` en el `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te sirva este ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var mydata = 
[
    {mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO AGRICOLA", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO OTRO", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO QW", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO2", pres: "10"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO3", pres: "30"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO4", pres: "40"}
];

    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });
    
    
    $('#tableGroup').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata 
    });
    
    merge();
    });
    
function merge() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableGroup');
    var rowLength = table.rows.length - 1;
    var count = 0;
    var columna = 1; //Importante no de columna donde se buscan los repetidos en este caso PRES index 1
    var row = table.rows[1].cells[columna].innerHTML;
    var saveIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i += 1) {
        console.log(row);
        if (row === table.rows[i].cells[columna].innerHTML) {
            count++;
        } else {
            row === table.rows[i].cells[columna].innerHTML;
            mergeRows(saveIndex, count);
            saveIndex = i;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
};

function mergeRows(index, rowspan) {
    console.log('merging,', index + ',', rowspan);
    $('#tableGroup').bootstrapTable('mergeCells', {
        index: index,
        field: 'pres',
        rowspan: rowspan
    });

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Data Addition</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>NORMAL</h1>
        <table id="table" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="mcNombre">Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="pres">PRES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <h1>Agrupado</h1>
        <table id="tableGroup" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="mcNombre">Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="pres">PRES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Supongamos que quiero hacer esto mismo pero son htlm comun y corriente sin utlizar boostrapTable:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//Supongamos que mydata viene de un AJAX o de done sea
var mydata = 
[
    {mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO AGRICOLA", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO OTRO", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "ACOLCHADO QW", pres: "20"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO2", pres: "10"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO3", pres: "30"}
    ,{mcNombre: "DATO4", pres: "40"}
];

  //tengo la tala con los datos originales
  crearTablaHTML(mydata,"table");
  
  //tengo la tala donde se utilizara el merge
  crearTablaHTML(mydata,"tableGroup");
    
    merge();
    
    //Borra los TR que hayan quedado de mas...
    fixTable();
    });
    
function crearTablaHTML(data,tableId){
//console.log(data);
  $('#' + tableId).html('');
  var strTabla = '<table class="table table-hover"><thead><tr>'  
                  +'<th>Nombre</th>'
                  +'<th>PRES</th></tr>'
                  + '</thead><tbody>';
  $.each(data,function(i,v){
    strTabla += '<tr>'
                +'<td>' + v.mcNombre + '</td>'
                +'<td>' + v.pres + '</td>'
                +'</tr>';
  })
  strTabla += '</tbody><table>';
  //Renderizo el texto HTML en la tabla
  //console.log(strTabla);
  $('#' + tableId).append(strTabla);
}
    
function merge() {
    //var table = document.getElementById('tableGroup');
    var rows = $('#tableGroup tbody tr');
    //console.log(rows);
    //console.log(rows.length);
    var rowLength = rows.length;//table.rows.length - 1;
    var count = 0;
    var columna = 1; //Importante no de columna donde se buscan los repetidos en este caso PRES index 1
    
    var row = $(rows[0]).find(' td:eq(1)')[0].innerHTML;//table.rows[1].cells[columna].innerHTML;
    var saveIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i += 1) {
        //console.log(row);
        
        var columna = $(rows[i]).find(' td:eq(1)')[0].innerHTML;
        //console.log(columna);
        
        if (row === columna) {
            count++;
        } else {
            row === columna;
            mergeRows(saveIndex, count);
            saveIndex = i;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
};

function mergeRows(index, rowspan) {
    
    if(rowspan > 0)
    {  
    $('#tableGroup tbody tr:eq(' + index + ') td:eq(1)').attr('rowspan',rowspan);  
    }
}

function fixTable(){
var rowspan = 0;
  $('#tableGroup tbody tr').each(function(irow,vrow){
      //console.log(irow);
      //console.log(vrow);
      var column = $(vrow).find('td:eq(1)');
      
      if(rowspan > 0 ){
        $($(column)[0]).remove();
        rowspan--;
      }else{      
        //console.log(column);
        var tieneRowspan = $(column)[0].hasAttribute("rowspan");      
        if(tieneRowspan){
          rowspan = $($(column)[0]).attr('rowspan')-1;
          //console.log(rowspan);
        }
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Data Addition</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>NORMAL</h1>
        <div id="table" ></div>        
    <h1>Agrupado</h1>
        <div id="tableGroup" ></div>       
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cristina Carrasco Angulo, tengo el mismo problema, pero quiero usar tu función sin usar BoosTrap table, ya que la tabla que genero no viene de ningún json, los datos los recojo con ajax de una base de datos.

Comment: @VictorJimenez mira intente hacerlo con HTML y JQuery, no se si esta correcto el codigo pero funciona para el caso de las pruebas.  Saludos

Answer (score -3):

el codigo con boostraTable lo he probado. Yo obtengo mi json de una base de datos mediante un metodo ajax. Esto es el resultado, pero a ti te servirá para probar con los datos que yo le paso.

El problema es que solo me agrupa Uc10castor y los demas permanecen sin agruparse. Y lo curioso es que Uc10castor vuelve a aparecer y se vuelven a agrupar pero solo los de Uc10castor, los demas no se agrupan.

La parte HTML es simplemente cambiar los datos de los títulos de cada culumna a request_code y contrata

$(document).ready(function() {

var mydata = [{"request_code":"LIM901","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM904","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM902","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM903","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM912","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM911","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"REC1101","contrata":"ProsegurR"},{"request_code":"OCT504","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL556","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL516","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL530","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL566","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL509","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"EQV414","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"BIL304","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"EQV411","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC409","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC417","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"SEM307","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SVA321","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"MMO101","contrata":"Sermanfer"},{"request_code":"TLF320","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"ELO221","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELC216","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELC211","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB225","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB230","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM205","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ASE605","contrata":"Otis"},{"request_code":"ENC401","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC402","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC403","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV415","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV418","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV419","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"LIM919","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"SIV322","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"LIM901","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM902","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM903","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM904","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM912","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"undefined","contrata":"undefined"},{"request_code":"OCT504","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL514","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL556","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL561","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"REC1101","contrata":"ProsegurR"},{"request_code":"OCL534","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL533","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"MMO101","contrata":"Sermanfer"},{"request_code":"SIV322","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SVA323","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SVA313","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SVA314","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"ELC216","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB225","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB230","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM205","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"undefined","contrata":"undefined"},{"request_code":"ELC227","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"EQV415","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC401","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC402","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC403","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"CAA324","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"OCL572","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"CTV312","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"ELM231","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"OCP570","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"EQV405","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC410","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC416","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC412","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV415","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC401","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC402","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC403","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV405","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV421","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC409","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC417","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"EQV415","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC401","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC402","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"ENC403","contrata":"Siemens"},{"request_code":"OCL509","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL514","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL519","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL556","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCS512","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCA518","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCP535","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCP545","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL563","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCT508","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"LIM901","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM902","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM903","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM904","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM912","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM919","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"undefined","contrata":"undefined"},{"request_code":"MMO101","contrata":"Sermanfer"},{"request_code":"MMO101","contrata":"Sermanfer"},{"request_code":"ELC216","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB225","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB230","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM205","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELC227","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM231","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"REC1101","contrata":"ProsegurR"},{"request_code":"SEM306","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SEM310","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"LIM901","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM902","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM903","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM904","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM912","contrata":"Uc10castor"},{"request_code":"LIM919","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"REC1101","contrata":"ProsegurR"},{"request_code":"OCT504","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL516","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL530","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL510","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL566","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL562","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCS512","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"OCL556","contrata":"Ferrovial"},{"request_code":"SEM307","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SIV318","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"ELC216","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB225","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELB230","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM205","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELC227","contrata":"Alstom"},{"request_code":"ELM231","contrata":"Avanza"},{"request_code":"CTV312","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"SEM327","contrata":"Artes"},{"request_code":"RAD328","contrata":"Artes"}]
    $('#tableGroup').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata 
    });
    merge();
    });

function merge() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableGroup');
    var rowLength = table.rows.length - 1;
    var count = 0;
    var columna = 1; //Importante no de columna donde se buscan los repetidos en este caso contrata index 1
    var row = table.rows[1].cells[columna].innerHTML;
    var saveIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i += 1) {
        console.log(row);
        if (row === table.rows[i].cells[columna].innerHTML) {
            count++;
        } else {
            row === table.rows[i].cells[columna].innerHTML;
            mergeRows(saveIndex, count);
            saveIndex = i;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
};

function mergeRows(index, rowspan) {
    console.log('merging,', index + ',', rowspan);
    $('#tableGroup').bootstrapTable('mergeCells', {
        index: index,
        field: 'contrata',
        rowspan: rowspan
    });

}

Comment: Victor, esta es la seccion de respuestas. Ya convertí tu anterior comentario para que estuviera en su sitio pero esto es demasiado amplio... si tienes una duda nueva, que no esté resuelta ya en el sitio preguntala tu mismo siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Al igual que ha comentado @lois6b te recomiendo realizar una pregunta si tu problema no lo encuentras en [es.so], además te invito a realizar el [tour] donde se explica el funcionamiento del sitio y conseguirás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed)